# nginx and workers and linux tcp sockets/lsof

Tags: nginx, lsof, unix-sockets

I started nginx with just a single worker.

```bash
ps --forest -fC nginx          
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     3615889   10118  0 14:18 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
nginx    3615890 3615889  0 14:18 ?        00:00:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

both processes listen on ports 80.

- pid=3615889 is master
- pid=3615890 is worker

#### so when a request comes from the internet - who will process it?

How the flow works from OSI layer standpoint? Am I wrong to assume that all requests will go to a master and then routed to the worker or workers can process requests independently?

I'm confused by both processes listening to the same socket (device #2151156)

```bash
sudo ss -ltnp | grep nginx
LISTEN 0      511          0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*    users:(("nginx",pid=3615890,fd=8),("nginx",pid=3615889,fd=8))
LISTEN 0      511             [::]:80            [::]:*    users:(("nginx",pid=3615890,fd=9),("nginx",pid=3615889,fd=9))

sudo lsof -i TCP:80
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   3615889  root    8u  IPv4 2151156      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   3615889  root    9u  IPv6 2151157      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   3615890 nginx    8u  IPv4 2151156      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   3615890 nginx    9u  IPv6 2151157      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```